# Map Function is iterating only once

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch-api, map-function

I'm to new to Javascript and trying to fiddle some concepts using map() function. But, in my case the iteration is only once. It's not displaying the other elements of the array. As, this api shows random profiles, so according to the APi response, I should see 20 persons but only one person it is displayed in the html whereas in the response I could see all the 20 persons.

```js
const configuration = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male",
  numberOfPersons: 20
};

fetch(`${configuration.url}&results=${configuration.numberOfPersons}`)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(mainResponse) {
    const authors = mainResponse.results;
    return authors.map(function(author) {
      const markup = `
      
        <div class="card">
        <img src="${author.picture.medium}"/>
        <p>${author.name.first} ${author.name.last}</p>
        <button class="primary-button">Call</button>
        </div>
      `;

      document.body.querySelector(".container").innerHTML = markup;
    });
  });
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```

Comment: But my requirement is to use Map function. So is there any way to use the Map function

Answer (score 2):

Each iteration you override `.container`'s innerHTML. Instead, you should return the html, join it together, then set the `innerHTML`:

```js
const configuration = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male",
  numberOfPersons: 20
};

fetch(`${configuration.url}&results=${configuration.numberOfPersons}`)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(mainResponse) {
    const authors = mainResponse.results;
    document.body.querySelector(".container").innerHTML = authors.map(function(author) {
      return `
        <div class="card">
        <img src="${author.picture.medium}"/>
        <p>${author.name.first} ${author.name.last}</p>
        <button class="primary-button">Call</button>
        </div>
      `;
    }).join("");
  });
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is iterating correctly, but you're using `innerHTML` on the same element over and over and over again, which will continuously overwrite the HTML you put in there previously.

Instead, append the generated HTML string to the `.container` element using the [`+=` Addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment):

```js
const configuration = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male",
  numberOfPersons: 20
};

fetch(`${configuration.url}&results=${configuration.numberOfPersons}`)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(mainResponse) {
    const authors = mainResponse.results;
    return authors.map(function(author) {
      const markup = `
      
        <div class="card">
        <img src="${author.picture.medium}"/>
        <p>${author.name.first} ${author.name.last}</p>
        <button class="primary-button">Call</button>
        </div>
      `;

      document.body.querySelector(".container").innerHTML += markup;
    });
  });
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```

However as pointed out in the comments, `map()` really isn't the proper method to use for this. While it does iterate over all the elements and works as intended for your specific use case, it's generally used in the context of making modifications to the array in question. You really should consider an approach using the proper methods, like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const configuration = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male",
  numberOfPersons: 20
};

fetch(`${configuration.url}&results=${configuration.numberOfPersons}`)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(mainResponse) {
    mainResponse.results.forEach(function(author) {
      const markup = `
      
        <div class="card">
        <img src="${author.picture.medium}"/>
        <p>${author.name.first} ${author.name.last}</p>
        <button class="primary-button">Call</button>
        </div>
      `;

      document.body.querySelector(".container").innerHTML += markup;
    });
  });
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```

Comment: Map is used to generate a new array where each element of the input has undergone some transformation.  

Mapping data onto markup representing that data is a common use case for map.